# MC Connector createdDate transformation

Tags: marketing-cloud, datetime, date, marketing-cloud-connect

I believe there are some date transformations applied automatically when synchronizing records from SFDC to MC via the Connector

I am talking about Created-date on Contact records for instance - I have noticed the date is in **CST** format  where the Contact records had it set up in **GMT** in SFDC

Is above a real thing or maybe my misinterpretation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a Yes/No answer then: YES.

Server time for SFMC is in CST.

> Time Zones and Synchronized Data Sources
>
> Date and time information
>   synchronized from the Sales Cloud to the Marketing Cloud change from
>   the specified Sales Cloud time zone to CST in Marketing Cloud. For
>   example, a birthday stored as 09/29/2016 00:00 AM in the Sales Cloud
>   in GMT changes to 09/28/2016 07:00 PM in the Marketing Cloud.

Reference

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_integration_for_your_account_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5